# Create Docker container with Nodev4.4.7 and Python3

Tags: python, node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Trying to create a docker image that has Python3 and Node v4.4.7 so that I can use it as a container for my project that needs both Python and that version of Node.

```
# Pull base image.
FROM python:3-onbuild

CMD [ "python", "./hello.py" ]
# Install Node.js
RUN \
cd /tmp && \
wget http://nodejs.org/dist/v4.4.7/node-v4.4.7.tar.gz && \
tar xvzf node-v4.4.7.tar.gz && \
rm -f node-v4.4.7.tar.gz && \
cd node-v* && \
./configure && \
CXX="g++ -Wno-unused-local-typedefs" make && \
CXX="g++ -Wno-unused-local-typedefs" make install && \
cd /tmp && \
rm -rf /tmp/node-v* && \
npm install -g npm && \
print '\n# Node.js\nexport PATH="node_modules/.bin:$PATH"' >>   /root/.bashrc

# Define working directory.
WORKDIR /data

# Define default command.
CMD ["bash"]
```

When I first tried it complained about not having a python script to run so added a basic python file: `hello.py`
that just has this:

```
print "Hello, Python!"
```

Then it complains about not having a `requirements.txt` file so added an empty `requirements.txt`

Now when I run `docker build -t isaacweathersnet/sampledockerimage .` it snafus during the node install with 
    `node-v4.4.0/benchmark/arrays/zero-int.js
     File "./configure", line 446
    '''
      ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'
The command '/bin/sh -c cd /tmp &&   wget http://nodejs.org/dist/v4.4.7/node-v4.4.7.tar.gz &&   tar xvzf node-v4.4.7.tar.gz &&   rm -f node-v4.4.7.tar.gz &&   cd node-v* &&   ./configure &&   CXX="g++ -Wno-unused-local-typedefs" make &&   CXX="g++ -Wno-unused-local-typedefs" make install &&   cd /tmp &&   rm -rf /tmp/node-v* &&   npm install -g npm &&   print '\n# Node.js\nexport PATH="node_modules/.bin:$PATH"' >> /root/.bashrc' returned a non-zero code: 1`

Comment: you have 2 CMD in your Dockerfile, only the last one will be used. Maybe it should be RUN instead? Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553353/what-is-the-difference-between-cmd-and-entrypoint-in-a-dockerfile

Comment: Thanks. That was probably it. Ended up using a different version of Python and a few mods and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution on Github that had Python and Node. No luck with Python 3+ but worked well with 2.7 
https://github.com/nsdont/python-node/blob/master/Dockerfile

```
FROM python:2.7

RUN \
cd /tmp && \
wget http://nodejs.org/dist/v4.4.7/node-v4.4.7.tar.gz && \
tar xvzf node-v4.4.7.tar.gz && \
rm -f node-v4.4.7.tar.gz && \
cd node-v* && \
./configure && \
CXX="g++ -Wno-unused-local-typedefs" make && \
CXX="g++ -Wno-unused-local-typedefs" make install && \
cd /tmp && \
rm -rf /tmp/node-v* && \
npm install -g npm && \
echo -e '\n# Node.js\nexport PATH="node_modules/.bin:$PATH"' >> /root/.bashrc

# Define working directory.
WORKDIR /data

# Define default command.
CMD ["bash"]
```

Answer (score 1):

There are [nodejs-python](https://hub.docker.com/r/beevelop/nodejs-python/) and [python-nodejs](https://hub.docker.com/r/nikolaik/python-nodejs/) (which is built on top of `nodejy-python`). It's worth to have a look into there.

`python-nodejs` provides `Node 10.x`, `npm 6.x`, `yarn stable`, `Python latest`, `pip latest` and `pipenv latest`. The versions used should be adjustable to your version needs. Use the [`Dockerfile`](https://github.com/nikolaik/docker-python-nodejs/blob/master/Dockerfile#L11) as basis and adjust the `RUN` section

```
RUN \
  echo "deb https://deb.nodesource.com/node_10.x stretch main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list && \
  wget -qO- https://deb.nodesource.com/gpgkey/nodesource.gpg.key | apt-key add - && \
  echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list && \
  wget -qO- https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add - && \
  apt-get update && \
  apt-get install -yqq nodejs yarn && \
  pip install -U pip && pip install pipenv && \
  npm i -g npm@^6 && \
rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

to the Node version you need. The `yarn` (dependency management alternative to `nmp`) and in case you need yarn) part can be removed.